# Schema - Star rating vanished from Google

Tags: wordpress, schema

Can someone please tell me how make it work on my site? My stars are gone, and i don't know what kind of schema structure i need to use to make them appear again.

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.animeonlinesub.com%2Fanime%2Fisekai-cheat-magician%2F

Tu voto: 09.4 16 votos

Answer (score 0):

Sorry what can of review system do you have on your site. If it is self-serving review, there is nothing that can be done as Google no longer accept this kind if review. You can see it here:https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful.html

Best wishes